# Returning an array of strings from a method - java

Tags: java

I have a class

```
package lab4;


public class CriticalClasses {

    private String course_name;
    private String[] critical_class = new String[3];

    public CriticalClasses (String course){
        course_name = course;
    }

    public CriticalClasses (String class0, String class1, String class2){
      critical_class[0] = class0;
      critical_class[1] = class1;
      critical_class[2] = class2;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return course_name; 
    }
}
```

this is my main:

```
package lab4;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CriticalClasses course;
    course = new CriticalClasses("Ingegneria");
    System.out.println(course);

    CriticalClasses classes;
    classes = new CriticalClasses("number1", "number2","number3");
    //System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(classes));
    //System.out.println(classes); these are comments because i dont know what to write
}
```

I cannot understand how to return all the inserted values in the main. I should use the toString method, but I can do that only for the element course_name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you cannot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to class CriticalClasses and You will be able to get array of strings

```
public String[] getCriticalClasses() {
  return critical_class;  
}
```

if You want just print them in Your main add

```
System.out.println(classes.getCriticalClasses());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use only one constructor for each object so you can use this

```
public String toString(){
    if(!course_name.equals("")){
      return  course_name;
    }else{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String string : critical_class){
            sb.append(string);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

and then just use:

```
System.out.println(course.toString());
```

and

```
System.out.println(classes.toString());
```

in your main